# Why is each boxplot in d3.box placed in its own svg element?

Tags: d3.js

At the risk of asking a silly question, why is each boxplot in `d3.box` ([code](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/box/box.js) and [demo](http://bl.ocks.org/4061502)) placed in its own svg element? (more generally, placed in its own container element.) Or to put the question another way, why does `d3.box` only render one component of a chart, rather than all components of a chart? (given that each boxplot is likely to share a common y axis.)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions. I'm sure there's a sensible rationale for this; it's just not clear to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, there is no reason to put everything into its own SVG. I don't know why it was done like this in the example, but usually you would have everything in a single SVG and group elements using `svg:g` elements.

The reason that most `d3` components usually only do one thing is that is makes it easier to combine them. If, for example, `d3.box` rendered `x` and `y` axes (or just one of them), you would have to provide options for people who wanted no axes, or a different axis layout, or anything else that isn't covered by how the implementer designed it.

If you're looking for something more high-level that takes care of everything, check out [nvd3.js](http://nvd3.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the link - good to have some additional code to delve into. On the one hand, it seems wasteful to have each boxplot maintain separate y scales (rather than axes - my error in the original question). On the other, I guess doing so makes the components much easier to combine.